# Faithful group actions for singleton group or for empty set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group, possibly a singleton. Let $M$ be a set, possibly empty. Let $\mu: M \times G \to M$ be a right group action. Let $1_G$ be the identity of $G$.

I understand [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Faithful)'s second definition of ***faithful*** as follows:

> $\mu$ is ***faithful*** if for each $g \in G$ such that $g \ne 1_G$, there exists $x \in M$ such that $\mu(x,g) \ne x$. $\tag{1}$

Later [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Faithful) says if $\mu$ is free *and $M$ is a non-empty set*, then $\mu$ is faithful.

Question: Given the idea that we can have $M$ as an empty set, I would like to clarify: Are these correct?

1. If $G$ is a singleton, then every action $\mu$ is faithful, whether or not $M$ is empty.
2. If $G$ is not a singleton, but $M$ is empty, then every action $\mu$ is not faithful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Correct. If $G=\{1\}$, then every action is faithful since the condition holds vacuously.
2. Also correct. If $G\neq \{1\}$, then there exists $g \in G$ such that $g \neq 1$. However $M$ is empty, so there does not exist $x \in M$ such that $\mu(x,g) = x$.